# How much time does Nemo spend trapped inside?

Tags: plot-explanation, inside

In the movie [*Inside* (2023)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt14781036/) we get hints of the passage of time - Nemo spends some time entertained with a pigeon outside; he follows the staff through the cameras in the building; he changes physically, his beard grows and he loses some weight as food gets scarce; there's snow and fireworks outside at some point, indicating perhaps New Year's Eve.

But how much time has actually passed since Nemo got trapped? Are there more precise clues in the movie (or is it stated in the script or by the director, etc)?